# Private IPs won't connect to TCP server, but public IPs will?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

I have public IPs connecting through to a TCP server running on my machine without any problems. However, when I try to connect to the server without going outside of the network (with a private IP), I fail to connect.

The client is supposed to connect and then send a serial number. However, instead the client sends an ACK upon connection then immediately after sends a FIN.

**Here is how I'm setting up my client when it works (using a GS2100M WiFi chip):**

```
sprintf (TXbuf, "AT+NCTCP=example.mydomain.com,211\r\n");
WF_TxAT(TXbuf, strlen(TXbuf));
```

**And here is how I'm setting up my client when it does not work:**

```
sprintf (TXbuf, "AT+NCTCP=192.168.200.105,211\r\n");
WF_TxAT(TXbuf, strlen(TXbuf));
```

**And finally, here is what the packets look like:**

[image: PCAPs]

**The server is set up using a module in Delphi called TIdTCPServer.**

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The client is connecting in both cases:  SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK is the tcp handshake. Looking at the TIME column, the client is sending the FIN-ACK only after 9 seconds..so it's timing out. (?)

Comment: @ABuckau I did notice that and I've been trying to figure out why it's happening. I set up a new simple server in C# using a different port, and the same exact thing was happening. Since the client should be sending a PSH immediately after finishing the handshake, I don't really understand how/why it's timing out since it shouldn't be waiting for anything.

Comment: I suspect a firewall issue. Something is allowing SYN and ACK packets between the client and server, but blocking ordinary data packets.

Comment: Seems strange, but is possible I guess. Other option is that the client isn't sending the data -- Changing the connection string should have no effect on how you send data...but perhaps the "CONNECTION MADE" response from the device (?) is different and your code isn't handling it correctly? Just a wild guess: I know nothing about the device, or the rest of your code.

Comment: How are you serially communicating with the wifi chip? I assume the chip is on some type of development board: do you have it plugged into a computer (if so, what software to communicate with it?), or are you uploading code to it? Either way, could you post the code where you handle the response for the AT+ command and also how you send data. I probably can't help, but it may help others to provide an answer.

Comment: @ABuckau The WiFi chip is hooked up to a board and accepts UART commands from another chip (the AT+NCTCP in the OP is one such command). Some of the commands are laid out [here](http://www.janus-rc.com/Documentation/AN045_-_S2W_HTTP_TCP_UDP_Protocol_Examples_1_9.pdf) if you want to take a look. The WiFi chip broadcasts a limited access point that you connect to, then I run through a configuration dialog which pairs it to a router on our network. I've sent the company that makes the chip an email, but have not yet received a response.

Comment: If you add me on Skype, I'll help troubleshoot; I don't think SO is meant to be used as a forum. username is same as here, plus "907"